# Material ui autocomplete with react-select to fetch db on every search

Tags: reactjs, search, autocomplete, material-ui

I am currently using Material ui v1.4.3 autocomplete. Material UI stated that this autocomplete is integrated with react-select.

I have followed the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/v1v1xp1xn3) which is working like a charm but in order to handle fetching larger data in the future, I would like to implement the search function to call the database whenever the input changes so that I am able to narrow down the data that is being fetched from the database.

Has anyone had experience on this? Because the static method from this code is blocking me to call any reducer function that is passed from my parent component.

What would be an appropriate way that allows me to catch the input from the user so that I am able to call my function.

```
function NoOptionsMessage(props) {
return (
    <Typography
        color="textSecondary"
        className={props.selectProps.classes.noOptionsMessage}
        {...props.innerProps}
    >
        {props.children}
    </Typography>
);
}

function inputComponent({ inputRef, ...props }) {
    return <div ref={inputRef} {...props} />;
}

function Control(props) {
////console.dir(props.selectProps.inputValue); i am able to get the user input here
// so i was thinking i can call my reducer somewhere here but no luck
// my function is passed from my parent component so i wish to call this.props.theFunction here
return (
    <TextField
        fullWidth
        InputProps={{
            inputComponent,
            inputProps: {
                className: props.selectProps.classes.input,
                ref: props.innerRef,
                children: props.children,
                ...props.innerProps,
            },
        }}
        onChange={(e) => IntegrationReactSelect.testing(e)}
    />
);
}

function Option(props) {
return (
    <MenuItem
        buttonRef={props.innerRef}
        selected={props.isFocused}
        component="div"
        style={{
            fontWeight: props.isSelected ? 500 : 400,
        }}
        {...props.innerProps}
    >
        {props.children}
    </MenuItem>
);
}

function Placeholder(props) {
return (
    <Typography
        color="textSecondary"
        className={props.selectProps.classes.placeholder}
        {...props.innerProps}
    >
        {props.children}
    </Typography>
);
}

function SingleValue(props) {
return (
    <Typography className={props.selectProps.classes.singleValue} {...props.innerProps}>
        {props.children}
    </Typography>
);
}

function ValueContainer(props) {
return <div className={props.selectProps.classes.valueContainer}>{props.children}</div>;
}

function MultiValue(props) {
return (
    <Chip
        tabIndex={-1}
        label={props.children}
        className={classNames(props.selectProps.classes.chip, {
            [props.selectProps.classes.chipFocused]: props.isFocused,
        })}
        onDelete={event => {
            props.removeProps.onClick();
            props.removeProps.onMouseDown(event);
        }}
    />
);
}

const components = {
Option,
Control,
NoOptionsMessage,
Placeholder,
SingleValue,
MultiValue,
ValueContainer
};

class IntegrationReactSelect extends React.Component {
state = {
    single: null,
    multi: null,
};

handleChange = name => value => {
    this.setState({
        [name]: value,
    });
    this.props.getSelectMultipleValue(value);
};

render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Select
                classes={classes}
                options={this.props.theUserFromParentComponent}
                components={components}
                value={this.state.multi}
                onChange={this.handleChange('multi')}
                placeholder={this.props.reactSelectName}
                isMulti
            />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal code example that illustrates your problem.